# Meta tag, Open Graph gerada por script

Tags: angular

Seguinte a metatag funciona normal quando adicionada no  do .html, mas quando utiliza as mesma metatag no Meta do angular não e reconhecida.

alguém já passou por esse problema para dar uma ajuda?

```
    import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    constructor(private meta: Meta){}
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.meta.addTag({name: 'og:type', content: 'website'});
        this.meta.addTag({name: 'og:locale', content: 'pt_BR'});
        this.meta.addTag({name: 'og:url', content: 'https://www.exemplo.com.br'});
        this.meta.addTag({name: 'og:title', content: 'exemplo.com.br'});
       let metaEl: HTMLMetaElement = this.meta.getTag('name= "og:title"');
       console.log(metaEl);
       console.log(metaEl.name);
       console.log(metaEl.content);
}
```

resposta do console.log:

```
app.component.ts:70 <meta property="og:title" content="exemplo.com.br">​
app.component.ts:71 og:title
app.component.ts:72 exemplo.com.br
core.js:19775 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
```

Comment: Se vc está tentando usar as meta tags em Angular para SEO, esqueça, não funciona! Só funcionará se vc usar o Angular Universal, que é um SSR (Server Side Rendering). [link](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-seo-making-angular-6-single-page-web-apps-search-engine-friendly-c8ec4ff2f549)

Comment: @GesielRosa verdade já testei ele, vou implementa-lo mais tarde pois tem uns detalhes que só podem ser carregados quando ele encontrar o browser, e tbm quero testa a performace dele pois ele utiliza o node ne